# Retrieve data from SQL with specific key, to C# application

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Lets say that I have a database containing the following:

```
+---------------------------------------+
| Key   Username  Firstname   Lastname  |
+---------------------------------------+
| 1234  user1     Firstname1  Lastname1 |
| 1234  user2     Firstname2  Lastname2 |
| 1234  user3     Firstname3  Lastname3 |
| 5678  user4     Firstname4  Lastname4 |
| 9012  user5     Firstname5  Lastname5 |
| 9012  user6     Firstname6  Lastname6 |
| 9012  user7     Firstname7  Lastname7 |
| 3456  user8     Firstname8  Lastname8 |
| 3456  user9     Firstname9  Lastname9 |
+---------------------------------------+
```

I would then like to retrieve the data in a C# application that sends it to an API with the following demands:

- The API expects the data to be sent with the "Key" so that will be one call for each key, but it will have to send all the users with that key in the same call.
- The value in the "Key" column is "unknown" (e.g, there could be added more values to "Keys").

I already got a class for creating all the users with a specific key, and the call to the API would look like the following:

- insertUser(key, usersArray), where "key" is the value from the "Key" column in the database and "usersArray" is an array created from a class that takes all the users with a specific "Key" from the database.

The main question is, to be more specific, which is the best way for retrieving all the users with a unique "Key" and use the API to insert them, then go to the next "Key" and insert all users with that "Key".

I hope that I am specific enough, otherwise ask me to clarify.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not clear at all what you are asking or what you are expecting as an answer. For any specific problem you are having please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please also read [How do I ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad.

Comment: Maybe select DISTINCT Key, Username, Firstname, Lastname from table

Comment: @Chuck, the rows are already distinct.

Comment: @jarlh, good catch, same key for different users, maybe it should not be called key! LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm very unsure on what exactly you're looking for, here. But assuming you've got the data access part down, LINQ might be your friend with this. Specifically, the [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
var allRows = GetAllRows(); // Returns IEnumerable<User>, where User has properties
                            // for Key, Username, FirstName, and LastName.

var grouped = allRows.GroupBy(c => c.Key);

foreach (var v in grouped)
{
    InsertUsers(v.Key, v); // v is IEnumerable<User>
}
```

This loads all records into memory on the machine, then groups them (still in-memory), iterates through each unique `Key` value, and uploads users for that given key.

This is a nice solution **if** you can afford to load all data into memory. This will depend on your circumstances, and may or may not apply.

If memory is a greater concern than bandwidth and time, it could also work to simply `SELECT DISTINCT Key`, then iterate through those, get relevant users, and upload them. Slower, but you only need to load one Key's worth of users at a time.

Comment: This was pretty much on spot, pointed me in the right direction. Used LINQ with a datatable which I enumerated. Thanks alot for your help!